# Повторяющиеся данные в базе данных

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

У меня проблема, есть форма где надо написать "Имя". Как я могу сделать чтобы "Имя" **не повторялось в базе данных**, тоесть что бы не было например 2 человека с Именем "Саша" в таблице

Comment: добавить уникальный индекс на колонку таблицы

Comment: A_I? как у колонки id?

Comment: зачем же AI?! Просто уникальный индекс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решений 2.

1. Опримальное настроить таблицу в бд, что бы поле было уникальное.

> ```
> CONSTRAINT table_1 UNIQUE (name)
> ```

2. Перед вставкой данных, вытаскивать идишник строки с таблицы с вводимим именем , и если ид существует то обрывать работу.

> ```
> select id from table_1  where name = $name
> if isset(id) and id >=1 {
>    return $name +"Занято";
> }else{
>    insert .....
> ```

Comment: Зачем делать два запроса: `select` + `insert` - если достаточно одного `insert`? При вставке будет выброшена ошибка в случае нарушения уникальности. Этого достаточно. Тем более, что в вашем варианте всё равно придётся обрабатывать этот случай, т. к. другой запрос от другого клиента может успеть вставить значение в таблицу между вашими `select` и `insert`.